# Change webserver's IP address depending on the hosted domain TLD

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, seo

I'm looking to build a CMS to manage several websites. Some will have a Spanish content and will be accessible via the domain `domain.es`, others will be in french, via the domain `domain.fr`, etc.

Since they will all sit on the same machine, this means they may be penalized by Google since it will geolocalize the hosting server's IP address to find out its location.

Here is my question: is it possible to have a different IP address for each domain, so that search engines geolocalizing the IP address will place the server in Spain when parsing `domain.es`and that the server is in France when parsing `domain.fr`? If it is possible, what is this technique's name ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not associating each domain with a unique IP. That is very easy, and is precisely what DNS is designed to do.

Your actual problem is finding (or building, more likely) the service that allows IP addresses from around the globe to be routed to a single server. That is something that is not only technically complex and un-orthodox, but will also cause horrible performance.

You'll either need to take the SEO hit (which I believe you may be over-emphasizing) or build a distributed system such that you can have multiple servers, one in each region you're servicing.

Another possibility for you to research is using a CDN like Akamai or Amazon Cloudfront. With these, user requests will automatically be directed to the closest CDN node to them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You could set up web servers in each country. You could have multiple IPs on the same server, with the same back end.

However I think you've got this wrong. I don't think the country where a server is hosted is that relevant any more, it's more about the domain name and acceptable speed. If you put all the content on one domain you'd probably get benefits from having a lot of useful, relevant content on one domain, if you spread it out you're diluting your SEO efforts.

In general, for SEO, aim to provide useful, unique content that is of value for users, is easily accessible, and is fast. Google will likely see it as good content.